# How can I create a signed APK from a keystore that is not my own?

Tags: android, android-keystore

I recently inherited a app, and I want to post the update but can't without the originally keystore and key. I got the keystore file and I am not sure if that is enough to create a signed APK from Android Studio that will be accepted by google play?

Answer (score 3):

Until and unless you have the keystore password, you won't be able to use that keystore to sign the app.
My advice would be to contact the original author of the app to provide you with the alias and password for the keystore.